# Не видны посты на стене Сраницы(Facebook) после отправки сообщения спомощью App

Tags: facebook-api

Кто делал постинг на стену Страницы с помошью Facebook SDK for PHP: почему сообщения видны только администратору страницы?
Создал приложение, сделал php код на сайте, отправляю сообщения, а они видны только админам?
Когда сам добавляешь вручную сообщения, то они видны всем.

Answer (score 3):

Была та же проблема. 
Оказалось, надо было приложение перевести доступный всем режим
приложение > Status & Review > зеленый кружок

"available to the general public"